# System level dependency for C++ STL

Tags: c++

I am faced with a wierd issue, i compiled my code on g++ cygwin compiler on my machine and compared its output with that which i got from ideone, and strangely both are different.

below is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "queue"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

class Student{
    private:
        int rollNum;
    public:
        Student(int id):rollNum(id){
        }
        int getRoll(void){
            return rollNum;
        }
};


#if 1
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    priority_queue<Student* , vector <Student*> , less<Student*> > pq;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
        pq.push(new Student(i));
    }
    for(; !pq.empty();){
        cout << pq.top()->getRoll() << '\n';
        pq.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

when i run it on my local system i get the output :
8
7
6
9
4
5
3
1
2
0

same code when executed in ideone on any c++ compiler version i get the output:
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
1
2
0

now my question is is there any system/os related dependency? because i cant make sense of this behaviour.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't include system headers (which include the standard library headers) using double quotes, use angle brackets. You also don't need to fill in all template arguments for the [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue). And if all you have is a condition in a loop, use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: Lastly, and very related to your problem: Don't store pointers in the queue!

Comment: Please rewrite your code to not use `new`. It's not needed here. (see fav C++ tutorial as to how.) C++ is not Java or C#!

Comment: @MartinBa , my motive was just to see the behaviour and use of priority_queue , not when to use new/when not to use new. i think my current question is not affected by new usage.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg , i was trying this code to use in my project where we have tonnes of big objects and need to use priority queue with custom functors, if we dont use pointers there will be huge memory issues.

Comment: @Arup - it *is* affected: look at the answer: You use new -> you store pointers -> pointers mess up your sorting. (Apart from a glaring memory leak) Don't use new. Store objects. Then the compiler will tell you that it's got no clue how to compare your object unless you tell it how to.

Comment: With modern C++ and move semantics, [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) is usually the best solution. But for the rule of zero to work really well you should avoid pointers, especially when stored in standard containers or container adaptors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The priority for this priority queue is specified by:

```
less<Student*>
```

What this does is that this compares the raw values of pointers to each instance of the `Student` class.

This is a completely meaningless priority, and it will give different results on different platforms; and this is not even guaranteed to give the same results each time the program runs with the same set of inputs.

So, yes, of course, there's a system/os dependency here.

Comment: so one cant use less/greater for complex user defined objects?

Comment: Of course you can, if the class implements the `<` operator. But this is completely irrelevant here because you are not storing "complex user defined objects" in your priority queue. You are storing pointers to a complex user defined object in your priority queue. If you want a priority queue of your `Student` objects, you must use a custom comparator class, whose `operator()` compares the instances of `Student` that the pointer parameters are pointing to.

Comment: @Arup You can't really compare *pointers* of unrelated "objects", you can only check for pointer equality or inequality. You can only compare less/greater than for pointers into the same "array".

Comment: @Arup, one can, just create a `std::set<Student>` instead of `std::set<Student*>`. Alternatively, create your own `less` function that dereferences the pointer and compares the underlying object, and then use it with your `std::set<Student*>`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Guys for clearing my doubts, based on your inputs i have the below code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "queue"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

class Student{
    private:
        int rollNum;
    public:
        Student(int id):rollNum(id){            
        }
        int getRoll(void) const{
            return rollNum;
        }
        ~Student(){
        }
};

struct StudentComparator {
    bool operator() (const Student* student1 , const Student* student2) const{
        return student1->getRoll() < student2->getRoll();
    }
};

#if 1
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    priority_queue<Student* , vector <Student*> , StudentComparator > pq;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
        pq.push(new Student(i));
    }
    while(!pq.empty()){
        Student* st = pq.top();
        cout << st->getRoll() << '\n';
        pq.pop();
        delete st;
    }
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

to sumup:
to use less/greater one needs to override < operator , but thats wrong as less or greater might be usecase dependant, for better to use comparison objects.